# Installing phpmotion in Windows server?

Tags: php, youtube, video-streaming, phpmotion

I want to build a youtube clone script in my webserver, I find a phpmotion cms.

I'm looking for the tutorial to install phpmotion in windows. I have a windows 7 operating system, but there's no tutorial about installing phpmotion in windows. I have planned to develop in localhost using xampp. Is there any tutorial about it? I've googling it and only find for installing phpmotion in linux. Can it be installed in windows?

If there's any other youtube script could you suggest me the best youtube clone script???

Answer (score 3):

You can use

clipbucket- [clip-bucket.com/](http://clip-bucket.com/)

vidiscript - http://www.vidiscript.co.uk/

These are useful to develop video sharing websites like youtube.